# HTML menu elements moves when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menu with HTML and CSS. The  menu looks fine, but when i re-size the explorer window, the menu items move EG:

Normal size window:
 [image: Normal size window:]

[image: Re - sized window:]

Below is the CSS:

```
body{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;

}

.logo{
    float: left;
}
#menubar{
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.mblinks{
  position: relative;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}
.mblinks li{
  display: inline;
 }
.mblinks li a{
  padding: 16px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some `min-width` to your menubar

change the css as below

```
#menubar{
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 900px;   /* Give the value as per your need*/
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `li`s are set to `.mblinks li{
  display: inline;
 }`.

This will make the list items display as text, so of course when the window width is modified, the items will move to fit within the confines of their parent.

You can counteract this by using `position: absolute;` but this will also take them out of the document flow and make it much harder to keep them in place with other elements around them.

Remember, this behavior is a feature, not a bug.

You can use `float: left;` on your `li`s but the element movement will be much the same.